# recognize objects in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to do an application with AI that learns to play the "You are offline" game from Chrome. I've read a lot about AI and about training but this questions is related more on android side.

Is possible in any way to recognize obstacles of the game ? I've played it a little and I can see only cactuses and birds at a point.

I did tried to search about this but it's pretty isolate and I hope there is someone with bigger experience than me who can help.

Thank you !

Comment: i'm not sure you can "read" what object is in the webview... that's pretty much the reason why he (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB_IGstiWlc&t=458s) needed to create is own game first.

Comment: I understand, well, I'll spend few hours to create the game first. Thank you